# Entity Model Help

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, entities

I have the following model in my database, but I'm a bit confused on what I should do.

If I have the Seat table how it is, it will end up creating so many rows, A - 1, A - 2 etc

How can I have this data split so it doesn't do this? I wanted the seatRow and seatNumber separate so I can easily match the values around the program.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given scenario I don't see the problem with having a large number of rows in the seat table. Which is what I believe you are alluding to.

Lets say you have a venue that has 1000 seats over 100 rows.

- If you split the tables you have 1 table with 100 records and 1 table with 1000 records.
- If you leave them together you have 1 table with 1000 records.

If you followed all normalisation rules you would only end up merging the two tables back together. The design looks fine for what it is. Placing the SeatRow and Number together would have no bigger or smaller impact on the number of rows. It's a smart idea to leave them split. Microsoft SQL Server would have no problem with this architecture and indexing it for performance. For Access and other file based databases I'm not familiar with the indexing policies so I can't comment.

Comment: So basically how I have it set out would be better in that case. but what about having A - 1, A - 2, A - 3, where seat rows and numbers just keep building up 1000's of piece of data.

Comment: What you have done is perfectly fine. I assume A is a row and 1 is a seat, yeah you'll get a lot. That's why you have a database to help you short list what you need to see. If you need only row numbers in a query, consider using select distinct =)

Answer (score 1):

You answer your own question: "a seat has 1 Row and 1 Number", so you can create these to tables and add foreign keys in your Seat table.

Comment: I was thinking that, to create a SeatRow table and a SeatNumber table but still felt it will be creating the same amount of data.

Comment: Of course you will obtain the same number of lines. If you really want to save rows and don't need more details about the seats, you can change it to store ranges of seats instead of seats. For example, (A, 1, 20, 2) to say row A, from A1 with 20 seats and an offset of 2 between each seat (A1, A3, A4, ..., A41). But I don't recommend it, imagine you want to add further informations later about a very specific seat (e.g. range A is for disabled people) you won't be able to do it.

Comment: I would probably have a Row table but not a SeatNumber table: Venue->Row->Seat.  Just because I can envisage talking about "seats in row C" but not "seats in SeatNumber 7"

Comment: OK I get you, since the seat row will be constantly used, like a - 1, a -2, it could be better to have 1 - 1 , 1 - 2, 1 - 3 for each seat row?

Comment: Don't be scared in creating more tables, it will always result in something much more flexible, increasing the expressiveness.